# Cannot resolve method 'getMap()'

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

in gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
def AAVersion = '4.6.0'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

}
```

in androidx fragment

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;


public class AgentsFragmentMapTab extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {

private SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
private GoogleMap map;



                    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
                    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
                    map = mapFrag.getMap();
                    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    map.setOnMarkerClickListener((OnMarkerClickListener) thisFragment);
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14f));

}
```

It's work fine. But when I upgrade lib:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

I get compile error in this line:

```
map = mapFrag.getMap();
```

error message:

```
Cannot resolve method 'getMap()'
```

Comment: Isn't it `getMapAsync` ?  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment